# How to get widget updating every 200/250 milliseconds without totally affecting homescreen drawing performance?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-widget, android-service, lag

I'm trying to write a widget where you can record sounds around you and I also show the user a little graph composed by 6 imageviews (6 colored dots) which are shown/hidden according to the sound level. Now to do this I obviously need to update the widget at least with a rate of 100 milliseconds but calling each time `AppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget`  make the homescreen lagging after a while. To update and record I use a service with an AsyncTask. What else can I do?

Comment: Using the partiallyUpdateWidget method seems to partially resolve the problem. I will update the answer if I find anything more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there is not a real answer to the question.
I faced with the method partiallyUpdateWidget that even of updating the widget without any lag in a short time period, it is slower than updateWidget so it did not resolved my problem.
I also think as many have said before that widget are NOT made to be frequently updated in a short time period (less than a second).
I hope this will help some of you.